# LiveUSB c убунтой "на борту".

Tags: ubuntu

**Доброго времени суток!**

Я пытаюсь создать LiveUSB с Ubuntu 11.10. И у меня возникли некоторые проблемы по этому поводу. В общем, делаю это у же в третий раз, а проблема никак не исчезает. У меня флешка на 8 гб, я разбил ее на два раздела:

```
1) 5.5 гб с FS ext2( для системы )
2) 2.2 гб под свап( Linux-Swap, раздел подкачки )
```

После установки на флешку и последующего запуска убунты оттуда, она начинает очень сильно подвисать...в чем может быть дело? Где моя ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста!

**P.S** До этого я пробовал и файловую систему ext4, вместо Ext2, но во-первых проблема не исчезла, а во-вторых, журналируемая файловая система для LiveUSB не совсем подходит, насколько мне известно. Пробовал без раздела подкачки, но безрезультатно...

Comment: Ну это не liveUSB. А непонятно что. Что мешает скачать нормальную полноценную Live версию и скопировать ее  на диск?

Comment: @KoVadim, т.е перезаписать диск с LiveCd версией?

---
Тем более, что мне хотелось бы иметь способность сохранять все изменения системы, данные, файлы, приложения на LiveCd-флешке.

Comment: вот ссылка раз http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

вот ещё http://voffa.ru/useful/ubuntu-live-flash-stick-windows.html

И если есть установленная убунта - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu
Обратите внимание на 6 скриншот - там как раз выбирают, сколько отвести места для сохранения пользовательских данных.

Comment: @KoVadim, предполагается, что убунту на флешке будет запускаться на компьютере без HDD, поэтому установка годится только на флешку.

Comment: а разве это что то меняет?

Comment: Просто у меня, как бы есть LiveCD с убунтой, я же хотел бы перенести ее на флешку, используя при этом флешку, как обычный HDD.

Comment: то что вы пытаетесь получит называется "bootable usb flash-drive", а устоявшийся термин "bootable live usb" означает либо образ которые можно развернуть на флешке либо флешку с уже развернутым образом. 


зачем усложнять жизнь себе и кому-то если можно просто скачать готовый образ и развернуть его на флешке. а потом импортнуть настройки с вашего "live cd"

Answer (score 1):

1. Необходимо смонтировать часть папок системы (/var /tmp и прочие часто изменяемые) в tmpfs - всё-таки флешка не предназначена для постоянной перезаписи
2. Попробуйте на другом, более мощном компьютере, возможно есть проблема с USB (раьботает на низкой скорости)
3. Проверьте с помощью утилит top и iotop - что вызывает замедление

Answer (score 0):

Скачиваете UNetbootin, вставляете флэшку. Указываете образ. Если вам нужно сохранять пользовательские данные, то там есть опция, надо выбрать лишь объем.